# Exim: Forward Based on Recipient in bcc

Tags: email, filter, exim, bcc, exim4

Currently I am filtering incoming mails by a .forward in the following way:

```
if $header_to: matches "(office|info)@domain.com" then
    save Maildir/.office/
endif
if $header_to: matches "whatever@domain.com" then
    save Maildir/.whatever/
endif
```

So I have a mail account, which receives mails for different addresses. Basically I want them to land in different subdirs based on the address the mail was sent to.

This works for mails where the recipient is in the `to`-header, but does not work if the recipient was in the `bcc`.

When a mail is received which was sent with the `bcc`-header, only the `envelope-to`-header matches the real address the mail is delivered to and it is mentioned in a `Received`-header

```
Envelope-to: office@domain.com

Received: from mail.other.domain ([1.1.1.1])
    by mail.domain.com with esmtps (TLS1.0:DHE_RSA_AES_256_CBC_SHA1:32)
    (Exim 4.71)
    (envelope-from <sender@other.domain>)
    id 1RO5xc-0001TF-Qj
    for office@domain.com; Wed, 09 Nov 2011 12:04:57 +0100
...
To: can_be_anything@whatever.com
```

I already tried:

```
if $header_envelope-to: matches ...
```

but this does not work, mails are not filtered at all even when sent with `To`-header (looks like the `Envelope-To`-header is not available in forward-files). Should I try to parse the (multiple) `Received`-headers?

How can I move mails into a subdir of the recipient based on the *real* recipient address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like I finally found the answer.

```
if $original_local_part matches "office|info" then
    save Maildir/.office/
endif
```

This checks only the local_part, but afaik could be extended to use the domain, too, with `$original_domain` (see [the doc](http://www.exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/ch11.html#SECTexpvar))

Answer (score 1):

The variable `$recipients` contains all (`to`, `cc` and `bcc`) recipients. Have you tried it?